# MySQL Concat Chinese Character Return NULL

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, string-concatenation, mysql-5.5, collate

I want to search with LIKE operator in two column of a table. Column names are : person_first_name, person_last_name . And i found a way for the search two columns like one column. The way is columns must be **CONCAT** and search in the concated string but my values are Chinese language. I want to search in concated Chinese words. In earlier I have searched Chinese language with this way "*COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI*" but that's not work in concated string. I have tried many method but i didn't get true result.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM (`dm_account` a) WHERE CONCAT(a.person_first_name, ' ', a.person_last_name) COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%ANY CHINESE CHARACTER%' ORDER BY `a`.`createdate` asc;
```

But this query does not return to me any record.

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.person_first_name, ' ', a.person_last_name) FROM dm_account WHERE id=2184;
```

This query does not show me combined words. But this user has got name and last name.

Anybody can help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Table alias `a` not defined additionally not require **COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI** if column characterset is **utf8** and collation is **utf8_general_ci**.

You can check this example

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Records of person

```
INSERT INTO `person` VALUES ('1', '昌, 畅, 长 ', '富, 芙');
```

Query

```
SELECT  * FROM person WHERE CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE "%昌, 畅, 长  富, 芙%"
```

Result

```
1   昌, 畅, 长     富, 芙
```

Comment: Thank you and I will add a description for case-sensitive usage because needs for search process. Something first name were Chinese character but last name typed with latin character or vice versa.. So for solve this problem I used LOWER function in first/last name like these: 
SELECT * FROM person WHERE CONCAT(LOWER(first_name), ' ', LOWER(last_name)) LIKE '%lowered_words%';

Comment: You’re welcome,
Yes that is a solution but you dont need `LOWER` in `CONCAT` function if first_name and last_name fields collation is `utf8_general_ci`.

**ci** at the end of  utf8_general_**ci** means **case insensitive**.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(person_first_name, ' ', person_last_name) 
FROM dm_account 
WHERE id=2184
```

u ve used table alias `a` but not defined it